# clicking multiple elements at same time, what is 'this'

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, if-statement

I feel like there must be a much better way of expressing the following condition:

```
if(node.is('a') || node.parent().is('a')){
        foo
    }
```

I want this for elements that are wrapped in an anchor tag, and to be able to easily retrieve/manipulate the href when it's the direct target or the parent.

`<a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>`

When clicking the image as expressed above, the event seems to be only grabbing just the `<img>` and not the `<a>` wrapping it. I want to be able to play with both from a single click.

More detail on what I'm doing:
trying to make an interface that allows you to click to inline-edit certain text areas (some of which have links around them) and images. I have an `.editable` class that i'm listening for. I have it working with regular links and text; trying to figure out how to get image uploads going. [more code](http://jsfiddle.net/cutcopypaste/hpjWj/)

Comment: Can you show us some more code?

Comment: i added a large whack of code, though it's not all functioning in the jquery.  the bit in question is inside of the loadEditor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $img = $(this)
,   $a   = $img.parent('a');

if($a.length) {
    //Do stuff if img is in anchor
}
```

If there is no anchor the length will be 0. Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate it http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/2UMvj/

The alternative is to put the click on all `a`, but I'm assuming you need this logic only when an `img` is clicked.

If you need the code to fire off only when an `img` inside of an a is clicked you could do this

```
$('a').delegate('img', 'click', function () {
    var $img = $(this)
    ,   $a   = $img.parent();
});
```

An example of this is http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/BS54P/

Answer (score 1):

```
function whoGotClicked(who){
if (node.is("a"))
     alert("im an anchor");
    else
        alert("im a"+node.get(0).tagName);

}

$("img").click(function(e){
    node=$(this).parent();
    whoGotClicked(node);
    return false;
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LZxRd/2/

Comment: Your finding the closest `a` and after that you test whether it is `a` or if its parent is `a`? Won't `node.is('a')` always evaluate to `true`?

Comment: i didnt know what the OP was trying to do with `if(node.is('a') || node.parent().is('a')){
` so removed it

Comment: Also don't use a global please! There fixed it for you.

Comment: it's inside a function that's being called on various clicks. i need certain code to execute if the click is on an `a` or `img` etc

Answer (score 1):

You can grab both by attaching click event to your link, from parent you can filter down to child. Like so...

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var thilink = $(this).attr('href');
    var thiscontent = $(this).html();
});
```

**EDIT**

Or if image is object of concern, which function above, you can add,

```
    var thisimg = $(this).find('img');
    \\then you can access any number of properties including src and manipulate them via
    var currentsrc = thisimg.attr('src');
```